# Get a counting Series from DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a pd.DataFrame, say df, as following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'No': np.arange(3), 'Status': [0,0,1]})
```

(i) I want to extract a pd.Series object from the second column of DataFrame above with substituting 0 with 'malignant' and 1 with 'benign'.
(ii) Then get a summary pd.Series of this new pd.Series that counting the number of 'malignant' and 'benign', which means the summary pd.Series consists two entries and has the index ['malignant','benign'].

Comment: can you show your expected out put ?

Comment: @Wen Just like a pd.Series  `benign  1 malignant   2`, where `benign` and `malignant` are indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.assign(Status=df.Status.map({0:'maglinant',1:'benign'}))
Out[169]: 
   No     Status
0   0  maglinant
1   1  maglinant
2   2     benign
```

I guess you need

```
df.assign(Status=df.Status.map({0:'maglinant',1:'benign'})).Status.value_counts()
Out[256]: 
maglinant    2
benign       1
Name: Status, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great answer too! But I need to extract `Status` first.

Comment: @JingZeng can you make you out put , as dataframe format ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what u mean changing the index exactly, index means '0,1,2' below.

```
df.Status.replace({0:'malignant',1:'benign'})
0    malignant
1    malignant
2       benign
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing, I've already changed my last question. And your answer is exactly what I want in the first question.